# How to make jQGrid ignore an inner table

Tags: jquery, html, css, jqgrid

At my work, we have some very old tables with data, and we are trying to transform them to jqGrid. Sadly, not all the tables can be recreate from scratch in jqGrid, so we are using tableToGrid to transform the tables with data in jqGrid and have, at least, some functionalities like sorting and the css styles.
But we found a problem with one of our tables: this table in some occasions shows information using a nested table, and in those cases, tableToGrid collapses, because he can't detect that the td's of the inner table doesn't belong to the external table, so he added to the external table. The result? A mess.
So, my question is: taking in consideration the limitations (can't use SubGrid, for example, because the date is already displayed on the html), any of you knows a way to tell tableToGrid to ignore the "inner" table? I think the key here is to find a way to call tableToGrid for the external and internal table without intervention of one call into the another one.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Since you said

> a way to tell tableToGrid to **ignore** the "inner" table

you seem not interested to keep and use their contents (at least during the transform operation).

So you might merely insert this **before the transform operation**:

```
$('table table').remove();
```

Obviously you may have to write something more precise than `table table`, depending on the whole context.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason of your problem is the usage of `tableToGrid`, which is plugin to jqGrid created many years ago and almost didn't changed or maintained. For example the plugin uses `addRowData` in the loop (see [the line](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.6.0/js/grid.tbltogrid.js#L98)), which works very slow. The origin of the problem, which you describe, is [the line](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.6.0/js/grid.tbltogrid.js#L50) of the code

```
jQuery('td', jQuery(this)).each(function() {
```

which could be changed to

```
jQuery(this).children('td').each(function() {
```

for example or just

```
jQuery(this.cells).each(function() {
```

(see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_tablerow.asp) about the `cells` collection of every `<tr>`. One can just use `this.cells[i]` to access the `innerHTML` of the i-th cell of the row)

Many parts of the code of `tableToGrid` are oriented on very specific structure of the grid, which checkboxes, which allows to convert such grids to the grids with `multiselect: true` option. Is it what you need?

The code of `tableToGrid` consist from two main parts: the first one read the data from existing `<table>` and saves the data in the array of items. The second part create the grid using the data. If you know the structure of your existing tables then you can create the replacement to `tableToGrid` in very easy way. It's what I recommend you to do.